# How many women were with Imam Hussain? (At the battle of Karbala)

Tags: shiism, women, hussain, karbala, battles

As possibly many of you know, at the time of Imam Hussain (a.s.) there was a tragedy event which was and is famous as Battle-of-Karbala. For more info. you can read the following link:

[www.al-islam.org/the-tragedy-of-karbala](http://www.al-islam.org/the-tragedy-of-karbala-collection-of-texts)

I was wondering regarding its women numbers. In other word, I wonder how many women were with Imam Hussain at the event of Battle-of-Karbala? Is there any statistics concerning that?

**Note:** As much as possible, I’m looking for the Shia view (references). Although Sunni’s views would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

About the attendance of the women in the day of Ashura (battle of Karbala) there are several women who consist of:

- حضرت زينب، ام كلثوم، فاطمه، صفيه و ام هاني

  (As the daughters of Amir-al-Mo'menin Ali (a.s.)

---

- فاطمه و سكينه و رقیه

  As the daughters of Imam Hussain (a.s.)

  ---
- And:

  رباب، عاتكه، ام محسن بن الحسن، بنت مسلم بن عقيل، فضه النوبيه و ام وهب
  بن عبدالله.

---

**The martyred woman:**
**ام وهب**

---

**Source:**

- [fa.alalam.ir](http://fa.alalam.ir/news/1532194)

Comment: This site's main language is English, It would be better to translate Arabic text to English.